# Am I correct in my proof that $x^2+x$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am currently trying to prove that $x^2+x$ is continuous on the reals from first principles. Let it be noted that this must be done by first principles. I am struggling to pick the correct $\delta$, but I believe I have figured it out, is this correct?

Proof:

Scratch work: $|f(a+h)-f(a)| = |((a+h)^2)+(a+h)) - (a^2 + a)| = |2ah +h^2 +h|$

Then $ |2ah +h^2 +h| = |(h(2a+1) +h^2)|$ By the triangle inequality,

$|(h(2a+1) +h^2)| \le |h(2a+1)| + |h^2|$

By definition of continuity, $|h| < \delta$ and we impose that $\delta \le 1$.

Then $|h(2a+1)| + |h^2| < |\delta(2a+1)| + \delta^2$

Because $\delta \le 1$, we know that $|\delta(2a+1)| + \delta^2 \le |\delta(2a+1)| + \delta$ and we may rewrite this as $\delta |2a+1| + \delta$

This simplifies to $\delta(|2a+1|+1)$, hence if we choose $\delta = \text{min} \{ \frac{\epsilon}{|2a+1|+1},1\}$ we will find $|f(a+h)-f(a)| < \epsilon$.
Is this correct?

Comment: Your math is correct, but I do have one comment: “By definition of continuity, $|h|<\delta$” is wrong, or at least awkward. You should say “If $|h|<\delta$, then …”, or “Assume/let $|h|<\delta$”, or similar.

Comment: According to your goal (struggling to pick the correct $\delta$) this is great.  But never show this to anyone else.  When you write it up you say "Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta = \text{min} \{ \frac{\epsilon}{|2a+1|+1},1\}$.  It follows that ...etc."  If someone says "Where did that come from?" just shrug.

Comment: Can’t our proof just be “because it’s a polynomial it’s continuous”?

Comment: @B.S.Thomson I'll keep that in mind (haha). So my $\delta$ seems reasonable then?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw The problem is proving it from first principles. You'd get away with that in calculus but not analysis. It is literally proving that a polynomial is continuous.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Well, not everyone necessarily agrees with that school of thought. For sure we should say “Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given” or similar. But there is something to be said for transparency in how we find magic constants. I would personally like a presentation where the whole estimation is done in terms of $h$, and then at the very end $\delta$ is introduced (and by then the reason for the choice of $\delta$ will be clear). In any case, “just shrug when asked” is not a very productive attitude to be taught IMO; not even in maths.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson That said, I agree that learners of maths often have trouble cutting to the bone of their proofs (or just saying things in a sensical order), so I do see where you’re coming from

Answer (score 1):

It should be a comment, but I make it an answer. Per your question, yes your answer is correct. Well done !

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My only worry was the $|2a+1|+1$ looked very strange to me. But if it is correct I won't complain.

Comment: That's the good part of your answer because you were able to use the triangle in the right place and right time. So it pays off several things at once.

Comment: Okay, well thank you for the verification!